# Converting png to jpeg increases image size

Tags: imagemagick, png, jpeg

When I convert png to jpeg , size of image is increasing for 2 percent cases. I am using convert command of imagemagick for this. Also able to handle alpha transparency factor by maintaing white background . But , I am not getting increase in size of image . It is very well known that pngs are lossless and jpegs are lossy , then what is the specific reason and what can be work around for it.[image]

Please refer above mentioned example pic

Answer (score 1):

Try decreasing JPEG quality setting. Jpeg uses Discreet Cosine Transform ([DCT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform)) to decrease the size of spatial data, but on high quality setting with high-detailed input images
you will get some size increase due to the fact, that data is not quantized enough and DCT-ed data needs some storage too.

Comment: I have one small doubt. What exactly do you mean about data not being quantized??

Comment: I'm not that good in English, but I'll try to explain: you perform DCT on NxM matrix, split by 8x8 squares, then through away areas, where result is not so far from zero. When you set quality too high, this threshold is too low and you will have to store even more data, then you had before.

Comment: Ok...thanx for explanation...so can we assume that in rare case only...png size may be smaller than jpegs